# Echo result from Linux file with dynamic filename

Tags: linux, bash

I have a tomcat server I am trying to get a list of info on for a project. I need to get the results from /etc/default/tomcat file. However some of my servers are tomcat6 and some are tomcat7 so hardcoding the filename is not going to work.

How would I dynamically insert the filename in this batch script.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo Server Name: `hostname`     
echo CPU: `top -b -n1 | grep "Cpu(s)" | awk '{print $2 + $4}'` 
  FREE_DATA=`free -m | grep Mem`
  CURRENT=`echo $FREE_DATA | cut -f3 -d' '`
  TOTAL=`echo $FREE_DATA | cut -f2 -d' '`
echo Internal IP : `ifconfig eth0 2>/dev/null|awk '/inet addr:/ {print $2}'|sed 's/addr://'`
echo OS Memory: `cat /proc/meminfo | grep MemTotal | awk '{ print $2 }'`
echo Operating System: `uname -mrs`
***echo Tomcat Memory: `cat /etc/default/tomcat6 | grep Xmx | awk '{ print $5}'`***
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your last command can be simplified to single awk like this:

```
awk '/Xmx/{print "Tomcat Memory:", $5}' "$tomcatFile"
```

Pass `"$tomcatFile"` whatever tomcat filename from ver6 or ver7.

You can get output from both tomcat files in same command using:

```
awk '/Xmx/{print "Tomcat Memory:", $5}' /etc/default/tomcat[67]
```

Comment: Yes that's right @fedorqui `awk '/Xmx/{print "Tomcat Memory: " $5}' /etc/default/tomcat[67]` will give output from both files in same command.